# smartGWT: how to add items in selectOtherItem

Tags: smartgwt

I have create a selectOtherItem in my SmartGWT .

i have just shifted from GWT where we simply do

```
             listBox.addItem("some Item");
```

and to put the values coming from a loop and also to save the id against every item (for                                                      values coming from db)

```
             for(int i =0;i <list.size; i++){
          listBox.addItem(list.getName(i), list.getId(i));
               }
```

but i'm not able to do these stuff in smartGWT .
Now i am using selectOtherItem .
If you can please guide how i can do the same thing in smartGWT, which i have show above.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SmartGWT also has the same functionality. You can directly add the Strings to a `ComboBoxItem` or `SelectItem` as mentioned below:

```
comboboxItem.setValueMap("s", "a", "d");
```

OR you can also prepare a `LinkedHashMap`, to specify key-value pair as mentioned below:

```
LinkedHashMap<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
for (Obj obj : objList) {
    map.put(String.valueOf(obj.getId()), obj.getName());
}
comboboxItem.setValueMap(map);
```

Besides, you can also fill up a `ComboBoxItem` or `SelectItem` using a `DataSource`.

For further details, refer this [link](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#styled_combobox_category).